# visual studio extension - describe drop down list in vsct file

Tags: c#, vs-extensibility

How to describe DDL with checkboxes inside vsct file for ToolWindow VS Extensions (see image)?

[image: DDL with checkboxes]

I tried MenuController but without any success.